# How to run Apache ActiveMQ Artemis as a Windows Service using a different account

Tags: windows-services, activemq-artemis

I want to run ActiveMQ Artemis (2.10.1) as a Windows Service as a windows service on a Windows Server 2016. I followed the documentation:

> On windows you will have the option to run ActiveMQ Artemis as a service. Just use the following command to install it:
>
> `$ ./artemis-service.exe install`

It works very well as long as I switch user to an account with Administrator rights. However in the project I am working it would be preferable to run the service as a special "service user" account.

When one develops your own Windows service one can use the `ServiceProcessInstaller.Account` class/property to control which account is used for the service.

I guess this behavior is built into the `artemis-service.exe` binary and accompanying configuration file, `artemis-service.xml`.

However I cannot find any documentation or source code for this. Anyone knows?

Comment: Are there any errors when you run the service as a dedicated service user? Has the service user access to the Artemis directories and files?

Comment: @aventurin If I try to install the service using my normal user (without administrator rights) I get:


`C:\Artemis\bin>artemis-service.exe install
WMI.WmiException: AccessDenied
   vid WMI.WmiRoot.ClassHandler.Invoke(Object proxy, MethodInfo method, Object[] args)
   vid WMI.Win32ServicesProxy.Create(String , String , String , ServiceType , ErrorControl , StartMode , Boolean , String , String , String[] )
   vid winsw.WrapperService.Run(String[] _args, ServiceDescriptor descriptor)
   vid winsw.WrapperService.Main(String[] args)`

The same with start/stop on installed service

Comment: @MagnusJohansson Did you ever solve the problem? I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

According to [pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/5016f69daaa596f4efd5b743fff9ad9eb52eb8f4/artemis-cli/pom.xml) during build of Artemis `artemis-service.exe` is pulled from [Maven Repository Artifact winsw](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.winsw/winsw/2.2.0) what is from [WinSW on github](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/). According to its [documentation](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/blob/master/doc/xmlConfigFile.md#service-account) you have to specify the service account in the xml file:

> **Service account**
>
> It is possible to specify the useraccount (and password) that the
>   service will run as. To do this, specify a  element
>   like this:
>
> ```
> <serviceaccount>
>    <domain>YOURDOMAIN</domain>
>    <user>useraccount</user>
>    <password>Pa55w0rd</password>
>    <allowservicelogon>true</allowservicelogon>
> </serviceaccount>
> ```
>
> The `<allowservicelogon>` is optional. If set to true, will
>   automatically set the "Allow Log On As A Service" right to the listed
>   account.

Someone already tried to do something similar you are triying and opened the issue [register service as local service and not system service #121](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw/issues/121).

Comment: I would appreciate if you mark my answer as correct.